# Quandl For Loop NotFoundError Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, quandl

I have a list of 10 stock tickers that I want to retrieve the history for by way of a for loop. This is the code I have so far:

```
top_list = ['SLV', 'RKT', 'FB', 'AAPL', 'ATVI', 'TSLA', 'NET', 'BABA', 'PRPL', 'FSLY', 'MSFT']
for tickers in top_list:
    top_list_tickers = quandl.get('WIKI/' + tickers)
    print(top_list_tickers.head())
```

When I run the following code I get the following error

```
    raise klass(message, resp.status_code, resp.text, resp.headers, code)
quandl.errors.quandl_error.NotFoundError: (Status 404) (Quandl Error QECx02) You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and try again.
```

I tried inputting 'WIKI/AAPL' instead of my tickers variable and that worked fine. Any ideas why quandl cannot find the items in my list?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The fact that 'WIKI/AAPL' worked separately says nothing about the other ten codes you're trying to use.  SLV, NET, BABA, PRPL, and FSLY all appear to be invalid codes for the WIKI data source.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Quandl, are there any other data sourced you'd recommend? also thank you for responding